# Debian 9 wifi doesn't work

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

I've a problem. I've installed Debian 9 Stretch on my old Samsung laptop, everything is working fine except the wifi module. It says missing firmware when I hover over wifi at right upper corner.

I really don't know what to do.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

- 06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01) Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [144f:7179] 

Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge Kernel Modules: bcma
```

```
uname -a

 Linux ClearSkySoftware 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+dev9u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Welcome . Can you add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and `uname -a` ?

Comment: lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 - 06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01) Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [144f:7179] Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge Kernel Modules: bcma 

uname -a: Linux ClearSkySoftware 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+dev9u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: If the question is out off topic , why voting down the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official website](https://wiki.debian.org/fr/wl) to get the wifi working on BCM4313 you should install the `broadcom-sta-dkms` and the `linux-headers` package then load the `wl` module

Edit your `/etc/sources` by adding the `non-free` component :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

Update your package:

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```

Install the `linux-headers`:

To get the available `linux-headers` , run:

```
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

Install the appropriate `linux-headers` to your `linux-image` , there is an example:

```
apt install linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64
```

Install the `broadcom-sta-dkms`:

```
apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Unload the conflicting modules:

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

Load the `wl` module:

```
modprobe wl
```